# How to better visualize python file structure with VS 2022

Tags: python, visual-studio, pycharm, ide, visual-studio-2022

In PyCharm, I can check the structure of my current file using the "Structure" window. The figure below shows this window circled in red.

[image]

In Visual Studio 2022, all I could find was the drop down as circled in the figure below.

[image]

I find this to be quite underwhelming. Is it possible to get a slightly more informative file structure in Visual Studio 2022 for the Python files I'm working on? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the extension [CodeMap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OlegShilo.PyMap). It's not as versatile as PyCharm's structure window but it will have to do.